# Objective-c Why is the following date incorrect

Tags: objective-c, date

I was doing an assignment for my intro to mobile development class.
We had to get the seconds since a date and give how old the person is in seconds, I wanted to extend this and show the actual age of the person. Can achieve this by(check out my code)
When the date is set to the NEXT day so my birthday is tomorrow it is showing an incorrect AGE. 
Heres my code;

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [comps setYear: 2000];
        [comps setMonth: 11];
        [comps setDay: 25];
        [comps setHour: 17];
        [comps setMinute: 50];
        [comps setSecond: 01];

        NSCalendar* g = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

        NSDate* dateOfBirth = [g dateFromComponents:comps];

        NSDate* now = [NSDate date];

        double secondsSince = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:dateOfBirth];

        double actualAge = secondsSince / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365;

        NSLog(@"\nI am %.9f Seconds Old \nI am Exactly %.9f Years Old %@", secondsSince, actualAge, now);
    }
}
```

Here's my output:

```
2014-11-24 13:35:23.547 secondsAlive[4978:44040] 
I am 441661522.544027984 Seconds Old 
I am Exactly 14.004995007 Years Old 2014-11-24 18:35:23 +0000
```

Comment: There aren't exactly 365 days in a year, so your math is wrong. Leap years.

Comment: Makes sense now.. Is there a way to achieve my end goal then ?

Comment: Got it, instead of using 365 I used 365.242 and its displaying correctly. Thanks terry

Answer (score 0):

There is 365.242 days in a year not 365.